# Interface file for C++ class

Tags: c++, python, swig

I am new to swig. I want to write python wrapper for C++ files. Actually I am having so many C++ files which are connected to each. So I was trying with some basic program to check how swig works. Please let me know what will be the interface file for this and what commands to write for wrapper since it is .cpp file.

My prog is

```
class adi
{
public:
    int a,b;
};

int main()
{
    adi add1;// declare an instance of an adi variable named add1

    int sum;// declare an instance of an integer variable named sum

    add1.a=10;
    add1.b=20;

    sum=add1.a+add1.b;
    cout<<"Sum of two numbers in adi1:"<<sum<<endl;
}
```